# How to disable saving orders in admin panel in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

My task is to not save any orders in woocommerce admin panel and database.

All orders information should be sending on admin email. This functionality is working well but only with saving in admin panel.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hello. Of course, the answer to your question is "yes sure there is" but this forum is for getting help with coding.  Your question is off topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  If you can re-word your question and include examples of what you've tried, then people will probably help you out better.

Comment: @HowardE, I did not have to perform tasks of this complexity before.
I tryied:
1. look for similar functionality in the admin panel of woocommerce
2. look for a plugin that can do this
3. find a hook or filter with which I can "disable saving the order in the database and admin panel"
These attempts failed.
It is more difficult to solve on my own in a more complicated way, since I am not familiar with the logic on which woocommerce are built. I’m doing the frontend and I don’t know the php badly.
I hope that there is a simple solution of this problem.

Comment: Well... you might want to look at this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/ and this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/